# How to configurable Child product cost price get in magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, child

How to get configurable child cost price get in magento 2.

**`Thanks.`**

Comment: Do you want child products data from configurable product?

Answer (score 2):

You get cost price of child product like below.

```
$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
 
$_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
$price = 0;
foreach ($_children as $child){
    $price = $price + $child->getPrice();
}
echo "Total Price:". $price;
```

If you want price range of configurable product then you can do it by below

```
<?php
$currentProduct = $this->getProduct();
$regularPrice = $currentProduct->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');
?>
<div class='price-box'>
    <span class="price">
        <?php
            echo $regularPrice->getMinRegularAmount().'-'.$regularPrice->getMaxRegularAmount();
        ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Please check and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: i want count all cost price.

Comment: Ok, i will update my asnwer for you

Comment: I have updated answer. Please check

Comment: i am  not want to child price but i want to cost price.

Comment: So you can get cost price , same as price

Comment: How to get configurable product price

Comment: I have updated answer for you.

Comment: its get only price not getting cost price.So please explain me how to get ?